# How do I add interpolated values into an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 1D array and I need to add values into it so it'll match another array and then put them together.

For example, if the first array is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and the second one is `[4, 6, 8, 10]`. I want to create one array which looks like this: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

I've tried searching for it but with no luck.

any ideas?

Comment: Where should `7` and `9` come from? Neither array contains these elements.

Comment: What's the logic behind your expected output? maybe we can find it by checking your code, can you add the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: The logic is that I have these two arrays which are actually x vectors for a plot. both of them have their own y vectors. I want to create a single x vector and a single y vector, so I can plot it. The problem is the overlap they have. that's why I can't just add them, and I want the x steps to be the same.

Comment: Why not just find the max/min across both arrays and use `range`?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2 =[4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> range(min(l1 + l2), max(l1 + l2) + 1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

For arrays such as:

```
l1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
l2 = [40, 60, 80, 100]
```

You can take the step of each array and used their GCD as the step for the output.

```
from fractions import gcd
range(min(l1 + l2), max(l1 + l2) + 1, gcd(l1[1] - l1[0], l2[1] - l2[0]))
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: what about `range(min(l1 + l2), max(l1 + l2) + 1, 10)` ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be `10`, for `l1 = [5,10,15,20]` it'd be `5' for example.